# Code Igniter : base_url() at CSS file doesn't work

Tags: css, codeigniter, image, base-url

base_url() doesn't work at CSS file...

here's my php :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>css/style.css"/>
<body>
</body>
```

here's my css/style.css :

```
body {
  background:#356aa0 url(<?=base_url()?>img/background.png) repeat-x;
  color:#fff;
}
```

the text color change to white, but the image doesn't show up...
if i use url(../img/background.png), it show up...
but when i open url localhost/project/index.php/control/function/var1/var2, it doesn't show up...

It's Solved, Thanks every one... :]

i make php file at view folder like this :

```
<?php header("content-type: text/css"); ?>

body {
    background:url(<?=base_url()?>img/background.png);
}
```

and i load the php file i just make with function at controller, and then i link it :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>control/style.php"/>
```

It's work, Thanks guys...

Comment: Are your shorttags enabled? Can you post how your link tag looks like when outputted in view-source in your browser?

And you know, you can't post PHP tags in css files.

Comment: can you use php in a .css file ?

Comment: No. Only if the file is php-generated but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS file does not get parse as PHP file. If you really want to do something like that, rename your file as `styles.php`

OPEN the page and add

```
header("content-type: text/css");
```

This tells the page to be treated as a text based CSS file. Then you can simple echo your remaining CSS like

```
echo "
body {
....
....
";
```

---

To fix the `base_url()` not being accessible from `styles.php` set a session variable to keep that. You can keep this on your `index.php` of codeignitor.

```
$_SESSION['base_url'] = base_url();
```

Now, use this inside `styles.php`.

```
background: url("<?php echo $_SESSION['base_url']; ?>"/../../some.jpg");
```

Comment: i use include function from php or <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>css/style.php"/>??

Comment: @EsgiDendHigherCloud, Yes like that

Comment: @EsgiDendHigherCloud, But make sure, base_url() is accessible from within the styles.php

Comment: Why would it be? That styles.php (even if renamed to php) is not part of codeigniter PHP code? Pls explain. :/

Comment: i try <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>css/style.php"/>, but the base_url() doesn't work...but i try to make php file at view and call it with funstion, and it's work...Thanks man...

Comment: Try checking if your shorttags are enabled?

Answer (score 6):

You should do it like this

Structure of your files

```
myapp/
    application/
    system/ 
    css/
    img/
```

And in css write this

```
body {
  background:#356aa0 url(../img/background.png) repeat-x;
  color:#fff;
}
```

And now call it

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>css/style.css"/>
```

That is the standard way of doing it. Also your css is not dynamic so you dont have to worry about php code using in it. The structure i presented in the answer will surely use the styles correctly and load the images.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to make php file as css. Simply put your images file out of "application" folder, e.g on assets/img. Then edit your css file

```
.error {
  color: #D8000C;
  background-color: #FFBABA;
  background-image: url('../img/error.png');
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

call the css file using

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css" media="all">
```

It will absolutely works dude!.

Answer (score 2):

Get your base_url() out of the CSS file. That would fix the problem. You can't put PHP code in a CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

if your folder structure is:

```
YourAppFolder/
    application/
           public/
               css/
               img/
         system/
```

Then use this in your view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>public/css/style.css"/>
```

and in css use this for image:

```
background:#356aa0 url(../img/background.png) repeat-x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Replace this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>css/style.css"/>
<body>
</body>
```

With this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php base_url(CSS/style.css)?>"/>
<body>
</body>
```

Also replace the following in css/style.css :

```
body {
  background:#356aa0 url(<?=base_url()?>img/background.png) repeat-x;
  color:#fff;
}
```

With this:

```
body {
  background:#356aa0 url(../img/background.png) repeat-x;
  color:#fff;
}
```

NB: if it doesn't work, try use one dot(.) -> **./img/background.png**

Assuming your file structure is like this:

```
-ci
--application
--CSS
---file.css
--img
---background.png
--system
.
.
.
```

and your `base_url() : " http://localhost/sitename/ "`

Answer (score 0):

or you can write ...

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url('your css file from base url') ?>/>
```

this is your external css file

```
    body {
  background:url(<? echo base_url('your image path from base url')?>) repeat-x;
  color:#fff;
}
```