# How to set background-image in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, background-image, codeigniter-3

I started to use codeigniter few days ago and I am not able to set background image by css file.My controller(verifylogin.php) is this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
   $this->load->helper('url');
 }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login_view');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     redirect('home', 'refresh');
   }

 }

 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'username' => $row->username
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }
}
```

while the view(login_view.php) is this one.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>OpediaLab</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1></h1>
   <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>style.css"/>
<label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The css file contains just these two lines:

```
body{
background-image: url("C:/wamp/www/CI/application/views/immagini/Opedia_LAB.png");
background-color: green;
}
```

Now, I'm pretty sure that the css file have to be in a specific folder (I have seen many tutorial, but not all say the same thing). The last attempt I made was to put the file in "views" as shown in the picture [image]

I hope I was clear enough, and I know, this is because I'm very new about this framework.

This is what I see at any attempt to change what I did. No errors but no css effect.

[image]

UPDATE:

This is what I get from the console:

[image]

Comment: Try to put your css calling inside head.

Comment: HI @KetanSolanki, I just tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: As @KetanSolanki mentioned, you must place the link tag inside <head>. Now please open up the source from your browser to see if the URL is correct. Alternatively, check the Network tab in chrome devtools and reload the page to check for any errors. Most likely an issue with the path.

Comment: @user5913892 i have updated the code and changed the linking of your css file kindly check it..And point told by Mr. Aziz is also a valid point.

Comment: Also please avoid absolute paths in your CSS background-image URL....... use relative paths (it's relative to the location of the CSS file) should be something like `background-image: url(immagini/Opedia_LAB.png);`
`

Comment: possbile dupe of [codeigniter base url css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129319/code-igniter-base-url-at-css-file-doesnt-work)

Comment: You should have a assets folder for your css and images etc out side of application folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>OpediaLab</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('style.css');?>">
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1></h1>
   <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>

<label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Base_url will only reflect upto CI Folder (In this case) But the CSS file is stored inside application>>views>>style.css

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:::

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>OpediaLab</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>."application/views/style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1></h1>
   <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>


<label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user5913892 kindly show us the error which can be seen in ur browser's error console.

Comment: I don't get any error, this is my problem. I attach what I see in my browser, in the question:

Comment: @user5913892 Just press Function key F12 in your browser, Then search for console,You might get any error over there..

Comment: I update the question with the picture of the console. 
I think the problem, is that the path is `http://localhost/CI/localhost/application/views/style.css` instead of `http://localhost/CI/application/views/style.css`. But who said to add "localhost" to the path. I don't get it.

Comment: @user5913892 did you get this error in my code? Because i hve not added any word like "localhost"

Comment: Yes. But the problem is not your code. I just opened the config.php file in config folder and i saw this $config['base_url'] = 'localhost'; If I remove localhost the background color is green, but if remove the background color, I don't see any picture as background.

Comment: in the css file change the code like this :body{
background-image: url("immagini/Opedia_LAB.png");
background-color: green;
}

Comment: I solved. I moved "Immagini"  in `C:\wamp\www\CI` and also Style.css in the same folder. AFter that everything it works fine. Your css was correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use Codeigniter URL Helper base_url();

I recommend that you put your css style on a folder named assets same level with the application.

In your case the style calling should be:

from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>style.css"/>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>application/views/style.css"/>
```

and in your style.css
Change

```
body{
background-image: url("C:/wamp/www/CI/application/views/immagini/Opedia_LAB.png");
background-color: green;
}
```

to

body{
background-image: url();
background-color: green;
}

Hope this helps you.. Feel free to ask questions.. or feel free to comment if i had i mistake;

Please do take note that i coded it here ; I havent tested it.. But i have applied it my projects.. Have Fun!

Comment: It is best to have images in a assets folder out side of application directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
   body{
         background: url(<?php echo base_url('assets/images/bg_images.jpg');?>);
}
```

Comment: Or in your views you can write inline css just like : <style>
body{
  background: url(<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/bg_images.jpg);
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
 }
</style>

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:/wamp/www/CI/application/views/immagini/Opedia_LAB.png"
```

you are fetching image from application directory and its forbidden from user due to security reasons, so you can not fetch image from application directory, can do same way but image should be outside of application directory, you can use own directory like assets.

In application directory there is htaccess file, its deny all.

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```